# Power Series - differentiation and absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am having problems with the following exercise:

**Ex. 1.** Let

$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x-1)^n}{n}$

**(i)** Find the convergence interval.
Here I let

$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{n}$

where $y = x-1$.  I let $a_n = 1/n$ and and find that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \vert \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\vert = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \vert \frac{1+n}{n}\vert = 1 $

thus radius of convergence is 1. by substituting back I find that f(x) converges for $x \in [0,2)$.

*I am pretty sure this is correct, but if not tell me and I will provide more details on how I did it so that I can see what I did wrong.*

**(ii)** Show that $f'(x)=1/(2-x)$ at all points where $f$ converges absolutely.
From the previous exercise I know that $f$ converges absolutely for $x = (1-R, 1+R) = (0,2)$. I now find f'(x)

$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}n(x-1)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x-1)^{n-1}$

and we know that this series converges for $\vert x-1 \vert < 1$ thus by using the geometric series formula I obtain

$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x-1)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-(x-1)} = 1/(2-x)$

for $\vert x-1 \vert < 1$.

**(iii)** Prove that $f(x)$ = -ln(2-x) on the convergence interval.

This one I cannot seem to figure out. Any hints on how I can solve this?

Best regards Husky653

Comment: Integrate $1/(2-x).$

Comment: @zhw. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have issues with a similar exercise. I have $f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^n}{n(n-1)}$ and I have showed that $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^n}{n}$ and that $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ at all points where f converges absolutely. ( f converges absolutely whenever $\vert x + 1\vert < 1$. ) I am now asked to prove that $f(x)=1+x-xln(-x)$. I tried to solve this by doing the following $f'(x) = \int -1/x dx = -ln(x)$ and then I said $f(x) = \int -ln(x) dx= -xln(x)-x$. But this is not correct and I cannot see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have issues with a similar exercise. I have $f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^n}{n(n-1)}$ and I have showed that $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x+1)^n}{n}$ and that $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ at all points where f converges absolutely. ( f converges absolutely whenever $\vert x + 1\vert < 1$. ) I am now asked to prove that $f(x)=1+x-xln(-x)$. I tried to solve this by doing the following $f'(x) = \int -1/x dx = -ln(x)$ and then I said $f(x) = \int -ln(x) dx= -xln(x)-x$. But this is not correct and I cannot see what I did wrong.